# How do i parse this String data from my API into a List?

Tags: json, dart

Im getting my data from my DB in the following format, and i want to convert it into a List or something similar for further use.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":6,
      "first_name":"Gigel",
      "last_name":"Ion0",
      "age":35,
      "detail":"Gigel is 35 old"
   },
   {  
      "id":7,
      "first_name":"Marius",
      "last_name":"John",
      "age":40,
      "detail":"Marius is 40 old"
   },
   {  
      "id":8,
      "first_name":"Cosmin",
      "last_name":"Lefter",
      "age":80,
      "detail":"Cosmin is 80 old"
   },
   {  
      "id":9,
      "first_name":"George",
      "last_name":"Calin",
      "age":65,
      "detail":"George is 65 old"
   }
]
```

I'm a newbie to dart, still learning the how-to's , tried to parse it with no succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String jString =
      '[{"id":6,"first_name":"Gigel","last_name":"Ion0","age":35,"detail":"Gigel is 35 old"},{"id":7,"first_name":"Marius","last_name":"John","age":40,"detail":"Marius is 40 old"},{"id":8,"first_name":"Cosmin","last_name":"Lefter","age":80,"detail":"Cosmin is 80 old"},{"id":9,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Calin","age":65,"detail":"George is 65 old"}]';
  List users = jsonDecode(jString);

  for (var user in users) {
    print(
        "user = ${user['id']} last_name = ${user['last_name']} first name = ${user['first_name']}");
  }
```

The dart json parser maps an json array to a dart list<> type. See [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more) for more details.